# why does highcharts error on android 4.1

Tags: android, charts, highcharts

I'm developing a monitor app meet someproblem with chart.

I have used achartengine and it could be drag to extends the xlimit even i set a range.
For example, x range is [0,100] so i set xlimit to 0 then drag the chart it would be possible to [-10,110]. How to solve it?

Then i use highcharts (it's already used on the website), but it didn't support android 2.x and got error on 4.1 like this:

[image: Example]
[image: Emulator example]

so what's problem with it or is there any chart lib with timeline? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: So you would like to drag line serie and update values, or need something different?

Comment: @SebastianBochan   the problem is there any chart lib with drag line? Through i used a webview to instead ,not work well.Different on android2.2 and 4.x , and around 2s delay till the chart display while i used webview.